# Blazor Server Identity not working in production

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have been trying to solve this issue for a few days but nothing seems working! I have Microsoft Identity in my Blazor server app and it works perfectly fine on my localhost but when I publish it to Azure Web Apps (Linux) the identity doesn't work and return "Nothing found on this page".
Azure web apps uses a a free managed SSL certificate offered by Azure.

Any help is appreciated (BTW I'm a self taught programmer)

Comment: Can you show more details from `Application Logs` in `Diagnose and solve problems`. ?